How to handle nested association in Rails
I have two models in Rails:
# Product
has_many :product_prices
belongs_to :associated_product, class_name: 'Product', optional: true
has_many :associated_products, class_name: 'Product', foreign_key: :associated_product_id

# ProductPrice
belongs_to :product

Problem:
I want my has_many :product_prices association to also fetch the product_prices of its associated_products.
Current Approach:
I have this method that works:
def all_product_prices
  ids = [self.id, *self.associated_products.pluck(:id)].compact
  ProductPrice.where(product_id: ids)
end

However, this solution doesn’t fully satisfy my needs because I lose some of the benefits of having a true has_many association.
For example, I have a scope in my Product model like this:
scope :paired_with_countries, -> (from_country, to_country) {
  joins(:product_prices, product_prices: :store)
    .where(stores: { country_id: from_country.id })
    .where(id: ProductPrice.joins(:store).where(stores: { country_id: to_country.id }).select(:product_id))
    .distinct
}

The issue is that this scope only considers the ProductPrice of the current product and not those of the associated_products.
Additional Context
When I scrape different stores, I create two different products for the same item in different stores (e.g., Grocery Store A & Grocery Store B) and associate them using associated_product.
The idea is to show associated products on the product page, especially if the matching fails, so users can see the differences. I don’t want to duplicate prices between products, as that would lead to unnecessary data duplication.
Question:
Is there a way to modify the has_many :product_prices association to automatically include product_prices from associated_products? Or is there a completely different approach you would recommend?

Put simply: No, there is no magical way to define an assocation which is essentially a union between two different assocations. You can do a lot better than this attempt though by defining an indirect has_many assocation with has_many :associated_product_prices, through: :associated_products, source: :product_prices and instead of pulling all the IDs out of the the database you use that assocation to create a subquery.

ProductPrice.where(product_id: product.id).or(ProductPrice.where(id: product.associated_product_prices.select(:product_id)))

If you want someone to actually give you a runnable example make it easy for them. Include an example of the schema, data and the expected result and the actual models
in a minimal form so that they can just copy and paste it. Don't be lazy and use # Product instead of actually just writing class Product ....
